# unable to clean a project because of eclipselink.jar

Tags: jpa, glassfish, eclipselink, glassfish-4

I am trying to clean a project because of an unvailable servlet, but Glassfish 4 tells me it can't delete a file :

```
...\my_project\build\web\WEB-INF\lib\eclipselink.jar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to restart glassfish.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: this is not an answer, we all know it will solve it, but how do you resolve without restarting the server.